# return json using WebServiceHost

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, jsonp

One month ago I did a sample project that had a web service which returns a JSON response. That's the server source:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getData?callback={callback}&timestamp={timestamp}", Method = "GET")]
    Stream getData(string callback, long timestamp);
}



public class WebService : IWebService
{
    public Stream getData(string callback, long timestamp)
    {
        string response = APIManager.instance.getPrediction(timestamp);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(callback + "(");
        sb.Append(response); // indentation is just for ease of reading while testing
        sb.Append(");");
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));
    }
}
```

So my client in Javascript was able to parse the JSON:

```
function get_data_server(){
var theUrl = "**server_ip**/getData";
console.log("Consulta");
$.ajax({
    url: theUrl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Success");
    },
});
}
```

When I access to it directly from the browser it returns the json correctly. Also javacript  works well.

**My problem** comes when I try to reproduce the same behaviour in another project. I do (well, I think I do) the same but when I call the webservice from the browser it just downloads a file with the Json response inside. What am I doing wrong? I think I'm doing the same in both projects... it's seems simple and it's driving me mad.

Any other way to solve the problem would be also appreciated.